# Solving Absolute Value Inequalities "or" or "and" statement deciphering help?

Tags: linear-algebra

When solving equations such as $|2x-4|>-12$ and $|3x-4|<9$ how can one tell if it is an "or" statement or an "and" statement?
${}$

Comment: You have the word "and" in the equation. This seems fairly indicative. Is this the exact form the equation appears in?

Comment: No the "and" I added between the two equations is not part of the equations I am only giving example equations.

Comment: Then it essentially comes from the way they're presented. If two equations are presented and both must hold, it would be "and". If two equations are presented and either can hold, it's "or". It depends on what you're trying to solve. If you have an example of the exact syntax that you're seeing, that could help.

Comment: By the relation operator.  If $|x|\gt y$ then you have "or" but if you have $|x|\lt y$ you have "and".

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, absolute values "want to" get large.  Generally this means that if the absolute value is on the greater side of the inequality it is "or".  Using your first example, $|2x-4| \gt 12$ we first solve the equalities $2x-4=12$ and $2x-4=-12$, getting $x=8, x=-4$.  These are the boundaries of you solution region, so check a point nearby and see which side is acceptable.  When $x$ gets large and positive or large and negative, the inequality will be satisfied, so the answer is $x \gt 8$ or $x \lt -4$.  In your second example, the absolute value is on the lesser side and you will find the central region is the one you want, giving "and".

Answer (score 1):

When an absolute value inequality is presented, you immediately have two branches to deal with.

In the first case, given $|x|\gt y$, the two branches are $x\gt y$ and $x\lt -y$.  For positive $y$, these two inequalities are mutually exclusive, therefore only one can be satisfied and we can consider it to be "or".  If $y$ is negative, there is an "overlap" space where $|x|\le -y$ and both inequalities can be simultaneously satisfied, but this is to be expected with an "or" designation.

In the second case, with $|x|\lt y$, the branches are $x\lt y$ and $x\gt -y$, and $y$ must be positive for the original inequality to have solutions.  Further, both branch inequalities must be satisfied to satisfy the original, so we consider this type to be "and".

Comment: You are assuming $x$ is positive, so that $|x|=x$.

Comment: I was solving equations like:

| -6x | > 30
-6x > 30 or -6x < -30
 x > 5 or x < -5

| 3x – 4 | < 9
3x – 4 < 9 and 3x – 4 > -9
3x < 13 and 3x > -5
x < 13\3 and x > -5\3

“or” and “and” confuse me because I don't know which one is correct for an equation. The only way I found weather to use "and" or "or" was on my workbooks answer sheet. The problem is that it does not explain how to decipher if the equation is an "and" or "or".
But I think “abiessu's” answer makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @RossMillikan:  I think I figured out my sign issues, thanks for the heads up!